# Extreme delay when using text(), or anything related to PFont in processing on Mac

Tags: text, fonts, processing, loading

I'm still having the problem with processing, that when I use the `text()` command in any way or when checking my `systemfonts` with `PFont.list();` the sketch only starts running after about 8-9 seconds. Even a simple sketch like:

```
text("hello world", 10, 10);
```

Anyone had a similar problem or might know what could cause this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what seemed to be the problem. I had a lot of fonts activated on my fontExplorer which seemed to slow down the loading. After deactivating all of them and only keeping the system fonts, the sketch loads after half a second.